# How to get sum of counted records using group by in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am trying to get the sum of count which I get from group, match. How can I get the same.
I have this code...

```
VisitorCompany.aggregate(
      [   
        {
          $match: {
            $and:[
              { entry_date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } }
            ]
          }
        },
          {
              $group:
              {
                  _id:
                  {
                      day: { $dayOfMonth: "$entry_date" },
                      month: { $month: "$entry_date" }, 
                      year: { $year: "$entry_date" }
                  }, 
                  count: { $sum:1 },
                  entry_date: { $first: "$entry_date" }
              }
          },
          {
              $project:
              {
                  entry_date:
                  {
                      $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$entry_date" }
                  },
                  count: 1,
                  _id: 0
              }
          },
          { $sort : { entry_date : -1 } },
      ])
```

and the output is ...

```
        {
            "count": 2,
            "entry_date": "2018-12-12"
        },
        {
            "count": 1
            "entry_date": "2018-12-11"
        }
```

Is anyone have idea that how to get sum of count i.e. 3 (2+1), means total number of records before group. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post  the sample data as a JSON

Comment: @ManjeetThakur, I think there is no need of it, but here is sample

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "xxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "company_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ip_address": "103.231.89.108",
    "country": "Australia",
    "continent": "OC",
    "visit_date": "2018-12-12",
    "entry_date": {
        "$date": "2018-12-12T09:05:03.996Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: please check with date constraint  ` {
              $group:
              {
                  _id:
                  {
                      day: { $dayOfMonth: "$entry_date" },
                      month: { $month: "$entry_date" }, 
                      year: { $year: "$entry_date" }
                  }, 
                  count: { $sum:1 },
                  entry_date: { $first: "$entry_date" }
              }
          },`

Comment: @ManjeetThakur, I want to get the sum of count, which I got in result only or total number of records fetched. see the outpu

Comment: Add this query to your aggregation pipeline, this query gives you the sum of the count. `{$group:{_id:"", sum:{$sum: "$count"}}}`

Comment: @ClementAmarnath, not getting how this will work, any sample ?

Comment: Try one more stage at the last. `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": "$count" }}}`

Answer (score 0):

Below modified query of yours will be giving you the sum of count, I have just added the

```
$group:{_id:"", sum:{$sum: "$count"}}}
```

to the existing aggregation pipeline query

Modified query

```
VisitorCompany.aggregate(
      [   
        {
          $match: {
            $and:[
              { entry_date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } }
            ]
          }
        },
          {
              $group:
              {
                  _id:
                  {
                      day: { $dayOfMonth: "$entry_date" },
                      month: { $month: "$entry_date" }, 
                      year: { $year: "$entry_date" }
                  }, 
                  count: { $sum:1 },
                  entry_date: { $first: "$entry_date" }
              }
          },
          {
              $project:
              {
                  entry_date:
                  {
                      $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$entry_date" }
                  },
                  count: 1,
                  _id: 0
              }
          },
          { $sort : { entry_date : -1 } },
          {$group:{_id:"", sum:{$sum: "$count"}}}
      ])
```

The result

```
{ "_id" : "", "sum" : 3 }
```

Comment: I tried with the same, but it changing the output, as below,
    
     {
                "count": 2,
                "entry_date": "2018-12-13"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "entry_date": "2018-12-12"
            }

and its gives {  "_id": "",      "sum": 6  }

I want like {  "_id": "",      "sum": 6  }  , { "count": 2,  "entry_date": "2018-12-13" },
            {"count": 4,  "entry_date": "2018-12-12"   }

like both in the response, if not possible then total count with another output, so I will get it and add this with response

Comment: @RiteshDoomra - Please add some sample documents from your collection in the question part.